# How can you define something without giving it any type like integer?

Tags: c++

I could not figure out the part about " void change(Square& obj){obj.side+=y;} " how can you define a "obj" without giving it a type like integer or else. Also what does Square& obj does for this code? Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Increment;
class Square
{
    private:
    int side;

    public:
        Square()
        {
        side=2;
        }

        void print()
        {
            cout << "side of square is: " << side<<endl;
        }
        friend class Increment;
};

class Increment
{
    private:
    int y;
    public:
        Increment()
        {
            cout<<"enter increment value: ";
            cin>>y;
        }
    void change(Square& obj){obj.side+=y;}
};

int main()
{
    Square s;
    s.print();
    Increment t;
    t.change(s);
    s.print();
}
```

Comment: `Square` is too a type. In light of this fact, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Note that `obj` is just a parameter-name, specified in the method's arguments-list.  The fact that the code's author chose to name the parameter `obj` doesn't mean anything in particular; he could have chosen any name for it that follows the allowed syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In `void change(Square& obj){obj.side+=y;}` you are not defining obj, but saying that the method `change` receives a type `Square&` named `obj`. Square& is a reference to a Square, it means that when you call `change(s)`, s is not copied inside the function to be used, but a reference is passed and any modifications you make inside the function to the object s will be reflected outside of the function.

Then, if you were to change Square& for Square in change, you wouldn't see any changes to s after doing `t.change(s)`, since the function did anything it had to do with a copy of s.